# Lots of Intersecting faces when using 3d printing, how to fix them in batch?

Tags: modeling, faces

I am using Blender 2.7.8.

I have a lot of intersecting faces on a peice I am trying to 3D print. My usual strategy in *Edit* mode is to manually delete each face, select the verticies forming it, and reform the face using <kbd>F</kbd>. This is unreasonable at this point. I have tried to select them all, and do a *boolean* operation, but that doesn't work (*Intersect* deletes everything, *Union* gives no improvement with all the faces selected).

What else can I try? Is there anyway to identify the real problem interfaces? Pic below. (Sorry for the Blue tinge, idk why screenshots on my second monitor always do that, #linuxproblems)

[image]

Comment: You can try removing doubles, or if, that's not enough, a software like NetFabb can be used to automatically correct non 3d-printer compatible meshes.

Answer (score 2):

I hacked around this by:

1. Selecting all `intersectng faces`
2. Deleting `only faces`
3. Using `Make Manifold`

This reduced the number from 45 to 3, and I repeated the same strategy above on those 3 until there were 0.

Comment: Be careful doing this. Since you're deleting faces, Make Manifold will just fill any holes that are left without regard to the overall shape of the model.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes I size X, Y or Z minutely and this can clear intersecting faces, this has worked on several of my models.

Answer (score 0):

There is this plugin specifically for Blender that helps with correcting these types of errors. https://makeprintable.com/plugins